# Is .NET ComboBox bugged?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm using this code to protect last part of being showed in list.
This works fine but whenever I get the `SelectedText` of `ComboBox` return a empty string.
Actually it should return "First " or Am I wrong ?

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("First \0 Last");
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
if (comboBox1.SelectedText == "") MessageBox.Show("Empty string");
//Message box shown
```

**NOTE : I'm not looking for a solution to fix this**

Comment: I don't know anything about .NET, but the answer to the question about it being bugged will always be 'doubtful'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a bug.  If you retrieve the SelectedText value in a button Click event handler, the value will be an empty string. This is because the selection is automatically cleared when the input focus moves from the combo box to the button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext.aspx

You could just use `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx

Answer (score 0):

it's always best to use the `SelectedIndex` to pick out the text, e.g., `comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]`